# difference between www.xyz.com and xyz.com and how to redirect .htaccess

Tags: html, google-search-console

I have a site and am using Google Webmaster tool. I created the setting within the tool for the site twice: once as www.xyz.com and once as xyz.com. The statistics from both are different once I drill down into details.

I want to stick with www.xyz.com. How can I make everyone go to xyz.com be redirected to www.xyz.com? and will this harm my ranking or indexing in google?

regards,

sorry if the question is simple :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with htaccess, i use the following for forced www

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

although you might be best doing the following if if it is for SEO purposes

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301] 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.htm
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.htm$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/home.htm
RewriteRule ^(.*)home.htm$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/home.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)home.html$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

as this also removes any index or home page part of the url.

in webmaster tools in settings, you can also select always use www, which will merge the data for both domains under a single www domain (although you will be able to see both www and non-www listed in GWMT)

Comment: where can i find this option of merging in the GWMT interface? thank u

Comment: to get to the option, you open up "configuration" and then go to "settings". you get to set the Preferred domain in there.

Comment: done and if I copy the code you have above in the .htaccess, will it work? because yes my aim is SEO

Comment: the code above is the standard code i use to ensure that all traffic lands on the www version of my domain and all index traffic lands on / and not / and /index.php or /index.html depending on how the links are made. as long as you have the code above and the setting correct in GWMT, this will clean up your information and will also clean up any analytics data you run.

Answer (score 3):

Use preffered domain, more instructions here:

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=44231

> Specify a preferred domain:
>
> ```
> On the Webmaster Tools Home page, click the site you want.
> Under Site configuration, click Settings.
> In the Preferred domain section, select the option you want.
> ```

You could also use 301 redirect:
http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633

Comment: I did this but am also going to modify the .htaccess like the mate above is saying